# create an application which can track the location using open street maps

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gps, openstreetmap

I am planning to create an application which can track the location of a certain person using open street maps. But I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the sourcecode of [osmdroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/), an opensource reimplementation of google's maps app using openstreetmap. They even provide a jar you can use! Should get you up to speed in no time. And possibly the official documentation on [Location & Maps](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/)...